# Understanding .each loop and some syntax

Tags: jquery

So, I'm following a tutorial where we are making a youtube search engine that will display some videos from youtube. This was the first video where the instructor mentioned the each loop. I looked on JQuery documentation but still cant wrap my head around what exactly this each loop is trying to do. I was following well with the instructor until he brought in the each loop near the end of the code below. I'm not too sure what the instructor is doing with this loop. Any insight would be helpful

```
function search()
{
    $('#results').html('');
    $('#buttons').html('');

    // get form input
    q = $('#query').val();

    //run GET Request on API

    $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
        part:'snippet,id',
        q:q,
        type: 'video',
        key:'AIzaSyCadgai_XAKk2TYQH1f5lXrR5QEHWXowfA'
        },
        function(data)
    {
        var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        var prevPageToken = data.prevPageToken;
        // Log data
        console.log(data);

        $.each(data.items,function(i,item))
        {
               var output = getOutput(item);

        $('#results').append(output);
               }

    }
    );

}
```

Comment: It simply iterate over `data.items` (The first parameter) and the callback function (The second parameter) is appending each value in the collection into `#results` (A DOM element with id `results`) - The `i` is the current index being iterated and `item` is the actual item in that index

Comment: `$.get` is returning data, which is conveniently named `data` in this code.  Within `data` there is an array name `items`.   Therefore, `$.each(data.items)` is iterating through each of the items in the `items` array.  As it iterates through the items, `function(i,item)` is the way of assigning the current item to the `item` variable.  It then passes each item to `getOutput()` and appends its return value to `#results`.

Comment: oh.. this whole time I was under the impression it was function data(), not function(data). I guess thats what happens when I just mindlessly copy the instructor. What exactly does putting data in function() do? I thought we must name all functions. like function search(){ stuff here}, atleast thats what we have been doing in the course until now.

Comment: @Munt you could name this function (For example `function myFunc(i,item) { ..... }`) and then pass it to the `$.each` loop by doing `$.each(data.items,myFunc)` (Note that i only pass the name of the function without " **()** " after it, the `$.each` loop will invoke it for you, and you can also reuse this function manually, or with more `$.each` loops the same way)

Comment: @Munt: This is an anonymous function.  In JavaScript, functions are objects like any other object.  In this callback syntax you're simply defining an unnamed function (`function (data) { ... }`) which will be invoked.  *Inside* of the implementation for `each()` the function is named as the parameter to `each()`.  You can see a simple example of this concept here:  https://jsfiddle.net/rc23wLac/  Where a function is defined which itself *expects* a function to be passed to it.  Then I call that function and pass an anonymous function to it.

Comment: Thanks for the responsive guys helps alot. So what exactly is data doing inside function()? Is it like other languages where we have functions and have variables as parameters? If so, how do we know whether data is a string integer etc?

Comment: you can do `console.log(typeof(data));` or `alert(typeof(data));` and it will show you what type of variable it is

Comment: I see. So basically in Javascript, we can use our parameter, inside the function as well? I mean in java if we want to use the same variable data inside our function we usually have to use this.data = data. I should start reading more on the documentation side of things, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's basically just a loop, but using the jQuery function syntax.  The benefit of that syntax is when you want to loop over a selected set of DOM elements, since the core of jQuery's usefulness is the simplicity with which is queries the DOM.  While it *also* works for any collection, it's not always necessary (unless you just want to use the syntax for consistency).

`.each()` simply iterates over the elements it's given, invoking the supplied function on each one.  Within the function, `i` is the index (0 through the element count minus 1) and `item` is the current element.  (And those two parameters can be named whatever you like, to keep your code clear and understandable.)

Basically, this:

```
$.each(data.items,function(i,item))
    {
        var output = getOutput(item);
        $('#results').append(output);
    });
```

is reasonably similar to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    var output = getOutput(data.items[i]);
    $('#results').append(output);
}
```

Comment: hmm, how does the each loop know to do i++? this is default? So we have to specify if we wanted to change i by 3 each time for example? Also is data.items from the youtube API? I havent defined data.items anywhere in my code and suddenly we are just looping from the items.

Comment: @Munt: The implementation of the `.each()` function in jQuery increments `i`.  And yes, if you want to increment by anything other than 1 you will likely need to just write your own loop instead of using the `.each()` function.  `data` (in this case) is simply the object that comes back from the YouTube API (the AJAX call being made by the `.get()` function), and `items` is a property on that object (an array, specifically).

Comment: @Munt I don't believe you can modify the iterator of .each(). It will simply iterate, one at a time, over every element in whatever data set you are telling it to iterate over. Also, yes, data.items is coming from your ajax request. That is the data that the youtube API is sending you in response to your request.

Comment: @Munt jQuery is a library, so any functionality it has isn't default, it's just hidden from you. Internally it's iterating the first parameter and calling your function on each iteration. I'd recommend learning how to do things without jQuery so that all of this will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. What is an AJAX request? This course is called intro to JQuery, should I have taken a course on AJAX before this? I'm still confused on the data.items part...

Comment: @Munt: AJAX is simply an HTTP request that's made behind-the-scenes.  There are subtle differences, but you probably don't need to worry about those just yet.  If you request a page in your browser (type in an address and press return), the browser makes an HTTP request to the address and loads the page.  AJAX is simply a way of doing the same thing in code without affecting the currently loaded page.  So you can fetch data behind-the-scenes while the page is still open.

Comment: @Munt I am not one to recommend w3schools very often, but they actually have a great beginner tutorial on jQuery. It covers selectors, dom traversing/manipulation, AJAX, animations, transitions, really everything you need to know to learn basic jQuery. The link is here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: Yes w3schools has alot of great examples thanks for the reminder. I think I understand now. One thing I am wondering about still though, is exactly HOW data is storing all this information about our search. where are we setting our variable of data to have all this information?

Comment: @Munt: You're not setting `data`.  The `get()` function is collecting information from the AJAX request (which you can see on the network tab in your browser debugging tools) and is passing that information as an object to the callback function you supply to `get()`.  Notice the parameter for that function is called `data`.  You can call that parameter anything you like, and just update the code within the function accordingly.

Comment: But if it is not setting this information to data, why is it that when I do console.log(data);, and go to browser debugging tools, I can see all the information it is storing?

Comment: @Munt: *Your* code isn't setting that information, *jQuery's* code is and is passing it to your function.  `data` is the parameter of your function.  Anything which calls your function can pass any object to it.

Comment: So what is prompting JQuery to send this information to data? I mean I could have put a random variable like bob123 or anything instead of data, and then that variable would hold the information

Comment: @Munt: Yes, you can name your function parameter anything you like.  Nothing *outside* of a function needs to know what a parameter is named, whatever it passed to the function will be in that parameter.  I'm not really sure how else to explain it, this is part of pretty much every programming language I've seen.  When you define a function, you can define parameters that the function expects to be given.  When you call that function, you pass values to those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code, I can tell that the response that you are getting back from the ajax call is an object. Said object has a property called items. Since the instructor is "foreaching" the items property, I can conclude that it is an array. Therefore, the `.each()` is iterating over every item in the data.items array to perform an action on each of them.

Now, you have not included the code for the `getOutput()` function, but based on the rest of the code, I can see that it is generating HTML markup using the current item in the `.each()` loop. After getting the HTML markup from `getOutput()`, it is appending the HTML to an element with the id="results" which will display it on the screen (assuming the results element is visible).

Hope that helps you understand what it's doing!

Comment: Thank you very much